# SAS: Looping Through Folders to Import and Export Multiple Files

Tags: loops, directory, sas

Thanks in advance for any and all suggestions.

I am working in SAS for the first time to complete a (theoretically) simple task. I have a parent folder in a Windows directory which contains several sub-folders. The sub-folders are not systematically named. For example, if the parent folder is called "W:/Documents/ParentFolder/", then the sub-folders might be "W:/Documents/ParentFolder/ABC1D26/" and "W:/Documents/ParentFolder/HG34A/".

Each sub-folder contains several SAS datasets. In any particular sub-folder, some of the SAS datasets have the .sas7bdat extension and others have the .sd2 extension. Furthermore, no two sub-folders necessarily have the same number of datasets, and the datasets are not systematically named either.

I would like to write a program in SAS which looks inside each sub-folder, loads any .sas7bdat or .sd2 datasets it finds, and exports the dataset into a different folder as a .dta file.

There are too many SAS datasets in each sub-folder to do this task manually for each dataset, but there are not so many sub-folders that I cannot feed the sub-folder names to SAS manually. Below is a commented version of my attempt at a program which completes this task. Unfortunately, I encounter many errors, no doubt due to my inexperience with SAS.

For example, SAS gives the following errors: "ERROR: Invalid logical name;" "ERROR: Error in the FILENAME statement;" and "ERROR: Invalid DO loop control information;" among others.

Can anyone offer any advice?

```
%macro sas_file_converter();

/* List the sub-folders containing SAS files in the parent folder */
%let folder1 = W:\Documents\ParentFolder\ABC1D26;
%let folder2 = W:\Documents\ParentFolder\HG34A;

/* Start loop over the sub-folders. In each sub-folder, identify all the files, extract the file names, import the files, and export the files. */
%do folder_iter = 1 %to 2;

    /* Define the sub-folder that is the focus of this iteration of the loop */
    filename workingFolder "&&folder&folder_iter..";
    
    /* Extract a list of datasets in this sub-folder */
    data datasetlist;
        length Line 8 dataset_name $300;
        List = dopen('workingFolder');
        do Line = 1 to dnum(List);
            dataset_name = tranwrd(tranwrd(lowcase(trim(dread(List,Line))),".sas7bdat",""),".sd2","");
            output;
        end;
        drop List Line;
    run;

    /* Get number of datasets in this sub-folder */
    proc sql nprint;
        select count(*)
        into :datasetCount
        from WORK.datasetlist;
    quit;

    /* Loop over datasets in the sub-folder. In each iteration of the loop, load the dataset and export the dataset. */
    %do dataset_iter = 1 %to &datasetCount.;

        /* Get the name of the dataset which is the focus of this iteration */
        data _NULL_;
            set WORK.DATASETLIST (firstobs=&dataset_iter. obs=&dataset_iter.);
            call symput("inMember",strip(dataset_name));
        end;

        /* Set the libname */
        LIBNAME library '&folder&folder_iter..';

        /* Load the dataset */
        data new;
            set library.&inMember.;
        run;

        /* Export the dataset */
        proc export data=library.&inMember.
            file = "W:\Documents\OutputFolder\&inMember..dta"
            dbms = stata replace;
        run;
    %end;
%end;
%mend;
```

Comment: Are you stuffing the DTA files all into the same output folder? What if there is a name conflict caused by the same member existing in more than one of the source folders?  And if there is no name conflict then you only need to define one libref that points to all of the input folders.

Comment: Personally, I'd break this up differently. First you have a step that finds all the folders/files which is easy enough. You go through this file and figure out if you have duplicates, find names. Then it's a simple export that I'd probably call through CALL EXECUTE, not through a looping macro - easier to debug and test entirely as you're testing each component separately.

Comment: This code here illustrates that approach. The initial file listing code is stolen from SAS documentation - macro appendix. https://github.com/statgeek/SAS-Tutorials/blob/master/Import_all_files_one_type

Comment: Just wanna chime in: I really like your code - very clean, easy to read and well-formatted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can perform all the code generation in a DATA Step and submit via `CALL EXECUTE`.  The only part of the program that would be macro related is specifying the sas data root folder, the names of the sub-folders to search and the export path.

The program could be very similarly macro coded, but could be tougher to debug, and would require `%sysfunc` wrappers around the function calls.

Example:

```
/* Create some sample data in some example folders */

%let workpath = %sysfunc(pathname(WORK));

%let name = %sysfunc(dcreate(ABC, &workpath));
%let name = %sysfunc(dcreate(DEF, &workpath));

libname user "&workpath./ABC";
data one two three four five;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

libname user "&workpath./DEF";
data six seven eight nine ten;
  set sashelp.class;
run;

libname user clear;

/* export all data sets in folders to liked named export files */

%let dataroot = &workpath;
%let folders = ABC DEF;
%let exportpath = c:\temp;

data _null_;
  do findex = 1 to countw("&folders");
    folder = scan("&folders", findex);

    path = catx("/", "&dataroot.", folder);
    call execute ('libname user ' || quote(trim(path)) || ';');

    length fileref $8;
    call missing(fileref);
    rc = filename(fileref, path);

    did = dopen(fileref);
    do dindex = 1 to dnum(did);
      filename = dread(did,dindex);
      if scan(filename,-1) ne 'sas7bdat' then continue;

      xptfilename = tranwrd(filename, '.sas7bdat', '.dta');
      xptfilepath = catx('/', "&exportpath", xptfilename);

      datasetname = tranwrd(filename, '.sas7bdat', '');

      sascode = 'PROC EXPORT data=' || trim(datasetname)
      || " replace file=" || quote(trim(xptfilepath))
      || " dbms=stata;"
      ;

      call execute (trim(sascode));      
    end;
    did = dclose(did);

    call execute ('run; libname user clear;');

    rc = filename(fileref);
  end;
run;
```

Comment: Reverse the order of the function calls here `trim(quote(xptfilepath))` otherwise the trailing spaces are inside the quotes.

Comment: Good catch @Tom `quote(trim(` makes for much tighter codegen

Answer (score 1):

Thanks very much for your helpful suggestions. I used the following program to perform this task. It is largely based on Richard's example. I'm posting it here for the benefit of future readers; Richard's example includes additional code that may help you understand what this program does.

Additional files/folders can be accommodated by adding them to the "%let folders" line. (I write many file/folder names here.)

Note that I separate the sub-folders with three dashes ("---") because some of the files and sub-sub-folders have spaces in their names. Note also that for the .sd2 files, I was able to simply replace the instances of "sas7bdat" with "sd2" and the program worked fine.

Thanks again.

```
%let inputfolder = W:\Documents\ParentFolder;
%let folders = ABC1D26---HG34A---Sub Folder\ZH323;
%let exportfolder = W:\Documents\ExportFolder;

data _null_;
    do findex = 1 to countw("&folders.","---");
        folder = scan("&folders", findex, "---");

        path = catx("/", "&dataroot.", folder);
        call execute ('libname user ' || quote(trim(path)) || ';');

        length fileref $8;
        call missing(fileref);
        rc = filename(fileref, path);

        did = dopen(fileref);
        do dindex = 1 to dnum(did);
            filename = lowcase(dread(did,dindex));
            if scan(filename,-1) ne 'sas7bdat' then continue;

            xptfilename = tranwrd(filename, '.sas7bdat', '.dta')
            xptfilepath = catx("\", "&exportpath", folder, xptfilename);
            
            datasetname = tranwrd(filename, '.sas7bdat', '');
       
            sascode = 'PROC EXPORT data=' || trim(datasetname) || " replace file=" || quote(trim(xptfilepath)) || " dbms=stata; run;";

            call execute (trim(sascode));
        end;
        did = dclose(did);
      
        call execute ('libname user clear;');

        rc = filename(fileref);
    end;
run;
```